# jquery trigger anchor scroll on page load?

Tags: php, jquery, scroll, anchor

I have downloaded the jquery scroll script (http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/better-html-anchor-a-jquery-script-to-slide-the-scrollbar/) which will scroll to your anchor when you click a link. However, I was wondering if there was any way to customise this using php/jquery to grab an item id from the URL, then scroll to that item id when the page loads?

Here's the scroll js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.anchorLink").anchorAnimate()
});

jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

    settings = jQuery.extend({
        speed : 1100
    }, settings);   

    return this.each(function(){
        var caller = this
        $(caller).click(function (event) {  
            event.preventDefault()
            var locationHref = window.location.href
            var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")

            var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
                window.location.hash = elementClick
            });
            return false;
        })
    })
}
```

Here's an example URL with the itemid in it:

```
http://www.somesite.com/index.php?view=list&itemid=3
```

^^ so basically I need the itemid grabbed (using php I presume?) and then tell jQuery to scroll to that anchor:

```
<a name="3" id="3"></a>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for PHP here at all! You're in luck! There is a jQuery plug-in that can grab and parse the query string. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object. If you want to roll your own, just test the `location.href` property in JavaScript as it contains the query string. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp